# Can I change text in files inside a directory by using arrays?

Tags: python, shutil

I have composed a script:

```
import os
import shutil

drc = '`filepath-obscured'
backup = 'fiepath-obscured-backup'
pattern = re.compile('Test')
oldstr = 'test'
newstr = 'TEST'

for dirpath, dirname, filename in os.walk(drc):#Getting a list of the full paths of files
    for fname in filename:
        path = os.path.join(dirpath, fname) #Joining dirpath and filenames
        strg = open(path,encoding="Latin-1").read() #Opening the files for reading only
        if re.search(pattern, strg):#If we find the pattern ....
            #print path, strg
            shutil.copy2(path, backup) #we will create a backup of it
            strg = strg.replace(oldstr, newstr) #We will create the replacement condistion
            f = open(path, 'w',encoding="Latin-1") #We open the files with the WRITE option
            f.write(strg) # We are writing the the changes to the files
            f.close() #Closing the files
```

This script works as intended --> it replaces the text "test" in every file inside the directory with "TEST".

The problem is: 
I want it to replace several "oldstrs" with several "newstrs". 
Which I have stored in a .csv. However, I have no idea of how to achieve this, any hints?

so my csv contains in the first row all oldstrs and in the second all newstrs separated by commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a dict of values you want to replace, read from your csv and then store them in values
I assume your values are stored in test.csv

```
In [19]: values = dict()

In [20]: with open('test.csv') as f:
    ...:     lines = f.readlines()
    ...:     values = {line.split(',')[0].strip():line.split(',')[1].strip() for line in lines}
```

Here you can see the values you want to replace are stored in the dictionary

```
In [21]: values
Out[21]: {'test': 'Test', 'hello': 'Bye', 'Left': 'Right'}
```

Here i open one file and replace the text(Just implementing the logic you need I dont write it anywhere just showing you in and out)

```
In [22]: with open('test2.txt') as f:
    ...:     filedata = f.read()
    ...:     print(f"BEFORE {filedata}")
    ...:     for k, v in values.items():
    ...:         filedata = filedata.replace(k, v)
    ...:     print(f"AFTER {filedata}")
    ...:     
    ...:     
BEFORE test, hello, I wish i wish i was a fish, left right left


AFTER Test, Bye, I wish i wish i was a fish, left right left
```

Comment: Sorry that I only get back now, there was a family emergency... 

Unfortunately the code https://pastebin.com/aGvcB35p does not work. 
Can you please point out any drawbacks? It does not present an error message

Comment: Jesus, that's awkward: Forgot to indent the last part ... -.-

Is there a way to get the csv "table like" so that line[0]/element[0] get's replaced by line[1]/element[0] as for now it is like a list of pairs where line[0]/element[0] gets replaced by line[0]/element[1] and so forth